# VBA Highlight Cells When Other Value is Present

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to highlight certain cells in a spreadsheet when a value is entered in a different column. I realize this can be done with conditional formatting but, due to circumstances within the company, I must use VBA. (The spreadsheet is passed onto another program that can't read conditional formatting)

I am trying to highlight 11 different columns within my range of values whenever **ANYTHING** is entered into column L. For example, when a date it entered in L2, then C2, J2, K2, etc. are highlighted yellow.

Below is what I have come up with.. unfortunately, when I run the macro, nothing happens. I see it run, but I get no results - not even an error message. Thanks in advance for the time you take to help me out!

```
Dim rng As Range, r As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("From GIS")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("To MapCall")

Set rng = Intersect(sht2.UsedRange, Range("L:L")).Cells


For Each r In rng
    If r.Value = "" Then
        Cells(r.Row + 1, "C,J,K,Q,AI,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BR").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    End If
Next r
```

Comment: You have to use `Cells(r.Row + 1, "C")` etc - either individual lines or set up a loop. In your `rng` line you should specify a sheet too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try and change r.Value = "" to r.Value <> "" as you want to apply a color if something is entered in the range not when it is blank. Tweak it as per what you actually need. I am also not sure why have you used r.Row + 1? It that's not what you want, replace i = r.Row + 1 in the below code with i = r.Row.

Also it's a good practice to declare all the variables used in the code.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, clrRng As Range
Dim i As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("From GIS")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("To MapCall")

Set rng = Intersect(sht2.UsedRange, Range("L:L")).Cells
For Each r In rng
    If r.Value = "" Then
        i = r.Row + 1
        Set clrRng = Union(Range("C" & i), Range("J" & i & ":K" & i), Range("Q" & i), Range("AI" & i), Range("AV" & i & ":AZ" & i), Range("BR" & i))
        clrRng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Great! That does just what I was looking for! For clarification, I am using r.Row+1 because I want it to skip the row of headers. If there is an easier way to do this, I'm all ears. I don't use VBA in my job but have been asked to learn it for this project. This site has been invaluable! Thank you.

Comment: @Rmoore You'r welcome! Glad it worked. Stick with it if it works for you that way.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to [create a union of ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel).

```
Sub test()

    Dim Rng As Range, r As Range, uRng As Range, row As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("From GIS")
    Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("To MapCall")

    Set Rng = Intersect(sht2.UsedRange, Range("L:L")).Cells

    For Each r In Rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            row = r.row

            Set uRng = Union(Cells(row, "C"), Cells(row, "J"))  'Etc... Keep going with each column
            uRng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: So that is getting closer to what I am looking for! At least I get some highlighted cells! It looks like it is only highlighting cells PAST the range area.. so if J2 through J10 in the range, J11 is being highlighted only.

Comment: Past, as in the next row? If that's the case, it's because your code called for r.row + 1. You could remove the +1. I updated the code for `row = r.row` rather than `row = r.row + 1`. See if that helps.

Comment: I just reread you question as well. You were wanting to highlight cells when `L` was not blank. So I updated your portion of the code from `If r.Value = "" Then` to `If r.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: Thanks.. that should I been something I caught when I looked at the code anyway.. just one of those days where I've been looking at it all day and things start to blend together :)   Thanks for your help!